# Time Complexity of sorting a integer array using radix sort

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, quicksort, radix-sort

Sorting a array of integers  ranging 1 to 10^9 of length n (= 10^6) with quicksort will give us O(n * log2 n) time. But if we apply radix sort taking n as base we need only 4 pass over it.

My understanding 
Radix sort complexity is  O((n + b) * logb (k)) where k is the max value and can be written as 
n ^ c. 
O((n + b) * logb (n^c)) taking base b equal to n, 
O((n + n) * c) = O (2c * n)

and quicksort is (n * log2 n) 
radix sort is (2c * n)

max k (integer in list) is 10 ^ 9 
also n^c = k therefore c = 2.

and log2 n is equal to 20 for n = 10^6.

sort quicksort is taking 20n steps whereas radix sort is taking 4n steps.

Is radix sort behaving well in this scenario? 
Will it be advisable to use radix sort.

Answer (score 0):

With the given parameters, radix sort would take 2 passes (2 passes would handle a range of (10^6)^2 = 10^12). Quicksort is O(n log2(n)) under ideal cases, and it's more like O(n log1.4(n)) (~ 30%/70% average split).

Comment: So do you saying radix sort is performing well here.

Comment: I beleive it is going to be 4 passes 1st step in count sort is over the bucket to get prefix sum and 2nd step on the actual array. here actual array and bucket both going to be of size n. thus every count sort routine going to take 2*O(n). and 2 routine call to count sort will give us 4 * O(n).  Any ways are u saying radix sort is performing well here.

Comment: @pvjhs - Radix sort can be done with one read/count pass, incrementing counts in a 2 x n^6 matrix, followed by two radix sort passes.

Comment: Do you think radix sort is working well here. Or are there hidden steps which make it costly.

Comment: Using base 10^6 will consume most or all of cache. A smaller base will free up cache. Base 256 will take 1 read / count pass using a 4 x 256 matrix, then 4 radix sort passes for range up to 2^32 (0 to 2^32-1), but may end up faster due to cache.